# ¿Cómo puedo explicar el uso del subjuntivo en esta frase?

Tags: subjuntivo

*Lo quería tanto, que en vez de engañarlo prefirió seguir amándolo **aunque tuviera que hacérselo saber de un modo brutal**.*

¿Por qué va con el subjuntivo si se trata de un hecho real?

Answer (score 4):

En primer lugar, existen dos tipos de concesivas (de la NGLE):

> Las prótasis concesivas se suelen dividir en HIPOTÉTICAS y FACTUALES. Las primeras admiten paráfrasis con 'en el supuesto de que' y las segundas con 'a pesar de que';
>
> En las primeras, en las que *aunque* equivale aproximadamente a *(aun) en el supuesto de que*, se introduce una situación en el momento actual y se afirma que el hecho de que se haga efectiva no impedirá algún otro estado de cosas.
>
> En las factuales se describe una situación existente, y se niega que de ella se deduzca alguna otra que pudiera ser lógica o esperable, como en *Aunque vive en esta ciudad desde hace treinta años, mantiene el mismo apartamento que alquiló al llegar.*
>
> Las [hipotéticas] se construyen con subjuntivo, como en *Aunque insistas, no te hará caso*, mientras que las [factuales] admiten los dos modos, como en *Aunque lo (intento — intente) todos los días, nunca consigo hablar con él*.

Considérense las siguientes frases:

- Miguel siempre se quedaba leyendo hasta las tantas, aunque tenía que madrugar al día siguiente.
- Miguel siempre se quedaba leyendo hasta las tantas, aunque tuviera que madrugar al día siguiente.

En el primer caso, el que tenga que madrugar es una realidad que existe independientemente de que lea o no. Esto es, se sabe que tenía que madrugar, pero ello no fue un impedimento para que se quedara leyendo hasta las tantas. En el segundo caso, no se dice explícitamente que tuviera que madrugar; solo se informa que, sea cierto o no que tuviese que madrugar, aun así se quedaba leyendo.

Por lo tanto, si en este caso se hubiese usado el indicativo, esto es:

- Lo quería tanto que en vez de engañarlo prefirió seguir amándolo, aunque tenía que hacérselo saber de un modo brutal.

...se estaría diciendo que "hacérselo saber de un modo brutal" es una obligación o una circunstancia que se da con independencia de la oración principal. El significado deseado es que X va a seguir amando a Y, aun si ello implica tener que hacérselo saber de un modo brutal, y no que X tiene que hacer saber algo a Y de un modo brutal, aunque esto no impide que lo vaya a seguir amando. Por lo tanto, el subjuntivo es el modo apropiado.