# Construcción concesiva "por más/mucho que" en el subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo

> *Por mucho que lo **intentara**, no lograba eludir la presencia del marido muerto: por donde **quiera** que iba, por donde **quiera** que
>   pasaba, en cualquier cosa que **hacía** tropezaba con algo suyo que se
>   lo recordaba.*

¿Por qué los verbos **intentar** y **querer** tienen las formas del subjuntivo y el verbo **hacer** no? **Hacer** se refiere a la construcción concesiva *por más/mucho que* o me equivoco?

Comment: De hecho también sería correcto *no* usar el subjuntivo con el primer verbo ("Por mucho que lo intentaba...) o *sí* usarlo con el último ("...en cualquier cosa que hiciera..."). Ambos modos son correctos pero pueden transmitir significados ligeramente distintos. "Por donde quiera que..." solo admite el subjuntivo porque es una frase hecha.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta! Esto es lo que me interesa. ¿Cuál son estos significados distintos?

Comment: Pensándolo mejor, no hay ningún cambio en el significado. La versión con el indicativo podría poner un poco más de énfasis en la realidad de los verbos pero la diferencia es mínima. Lo he explicado un poco mejor en la respuesta.

Comment: *por mucho que lo intentara* = pero no lo intentó.

Comment: @Ustanak O sea que si oyeras la frase "Por mucho que lo intentara, no lograba eludir la presencia del marido muerto", ¿pensarías que no lo intentó?

Comment: @Yay Es que ese caso es distinto. Yo ahí interpreto el uso como una *intención*. Por ejemplo: dos personas hablando por teléfono, una le dice a la otra: me pediste que me *llamaras* - pero igual lo hice -. Sin embargo, en otro contexto, significaría que la acción *llamar*, no se llevó acabo.

Answer (score 1):

Ambas formas (subjuntivo o indicativo) son válidas. La frase se podría haber escrito con los verbos en indicativo o en subjuntivo y ambas habrían sido correctas:

> Por mucho que lo **intentaba**, no lograba eludir la presencia del marido muerto: por donde quiera que **iba**, por donde quiera que **pasaba**, en cualquier cosa que **hacía** tropezaba con algo suyo que se lo recordaba.
>
> Por mucho que lo **intentara**, no lograba eludir la presencia del marido muerto: por donde quiera que **fuera**, por donde quiera que **pasara**, en cualquier cosa que **hiciera** tropezaba con algo suyo que se lo recordaba.

La explicación es más o menos la misma que la de esta otra pregunta: [¿Cómo puedo explicar el uso del subjuntivo en esta frase?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16643/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-explicar-el-uso-del-subjuntivo-en-esta-frase/16644#16644). En resumen, las [cláusulas concesivas](http://www.gramaticas.net/2011/10/ejemplos-de-oracion-subordinada_847.html) pueden ser **hipotéticas** o **factuales**. Son hipotéticas cuando la subordinada describe una situación que, en caso de ser real, sería un impedimento para otra cosa; y son factuales si describen una situación que se da como cierta independientemente de la cláusula principal. Mientras que las primeras admiten solo el subjuntivo, las segundas admiten el indicativo y el subjuntivo.

"Por mucho/más que" es una locución subordinante que crea cláusulas concesivas. Que una conjunción cree cláusulas concesivas hipotéticas o factuales no suele ser algo inherente a la conjunción en cuestión. Más bien, es el contexto y la elección de los verbos lo que suele desambiguar. Así, "por mucho que" introduce una concesiva hipotética en (1) pero factual en (2):

1. Por mucho que Pepe me **pida** perdón, no se lo voy a perdonar jamás.
2. Por mucho que Pepe me **pidió** perdón, no se lo perdoné jamás.

En (1) el uso del subjuntivo no implica necesariamente que Pepe no pida o haya pedido perdón, pero tampoco indica que sí lo haga. El indicativo en (2) sí implica claramente que Pepe pidió perdón.

La locución "por mucho/más que..." suele ir seguida del subjuntivo. Cuando va seguida del indicativo, su significado es equivalente a "a pesar de que" (ver [§ 25.13g](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wnQRtCYaKZFoTFha)). En la frase de la pregunta, se da como factual porque los verbos de la oración principal ("lograba", "tropezaba", "recordaba") están en pasado, lo cual impide la interpretación hipotética. En otras palabras, la frase de la pregunta y las dos de arriba significan prácticamente lo mismo.

---

En el caso de "por donde quiera que...", solo se usa el subjuntivo porque es una frase hecha. Si se toma literalmente, la construcción "por donde quiera que" no tiene mucho sentido. Como expresión, significa "en cualquier lugar que o sea donde sea que" ([RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E8JIKmq)). De hecho, es común encontrarla como una sola palabra: *dondequiera*, o incluso *doquiera* o *doquier*, ambas existentes en español desde hace ya por lo menos siete siglos:

> E dio al trasllado que yo della fiziese, autoridat e interpuso su [decreto para que va]liese e fiziese fe, **doquiera que** aparesçiese, así commo faría la dicha carta oryginal, paresçiendo.
>
> Anónimo (1351). *Traslado de una carta de merced [Documentos del Monasterio de Santa Clara de Villalobos]*
>
> A esto respondemos que mandaremos dar nuestras cartas para los merinos e para los otros officiales, que lles tomen todo quanto lles fallaren por **doquier que** lo fallen fasta que paguen lo que ouieren de pagar en la taxación e lo entreguen al prelado para lo pagar al que lo quiere de auer por nos;
>
> Anónimo (1326). *Privilegio rodado [Documentos de la catedral de León]*